# Implementing the map function using only foldRight, foldLeft and unfold in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming

I have to implement the Map function using only the foldRight, foldLeft and unfold. This means that I have to loop through every element in the list and apply a function f to it.

I have declared my own list as follow:

```
abstract class IntList
case class Nil() extends IntList
case class Cons(h: Int, t: IntList) extends IntList
```

And I've implemented the foldRight, foldLeft and unfold functions.

and the implementation of the new map function:

```
def map(ls: IntList, f: Int => Int): IntList = // ??
```

I've been thinking  for a while now, but I don't have a clue where to begin. I may not use recursion in the map function. I'm pretty sure that I have to combine the power of fold and unfold together. Unfold returns a IntList, which is the return type of map. But I'm not sure what I have to give with this function.

Anyone has a clue? :)

Comment: Hint: You only need *either* foldLeft *or* foldRight *or* unfold. The simplest solution is with foldRight.

Comment: This is a pretty standard task. If you don't have any idea of how to start, google it.

Comment: I've alreayd googled for a while, but I can't find a similar topic on this problem. I know it's a standard task and it shouldn't be hard, but I just need a starting point.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg How do you implement map using `unfold`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match the types, fill in the arguments to match.

For instance, if you are going to use `foldRight`, then `B` must be `IntList`, because that's the type returned by `map`. Now fill in the arguments to `foldRight` with whatever values you have that match the types.

Comment: Hmm... I've searched some about the generic types and I think I understand now how they work. Would something like the following work? In this case, B is of type IntList:    

MyList.foldRight(as, Nil(), (x : Int, y : IntList) => Cons(f(x),Nil()))

Comment: @Devos50 Do I look like a REPL? Try it out! It won't bite you. :-)

Comment: Hehe, true, but I've written some tests and I think I got it :)

MyList.foldRight(as, Nil(), (x : Int, y : IntList) => Cons(f(x),y))

I had to replace Nil() by y because otherwise the recursion would stop on the first call already! I have to get more familiar with these generic type I guess.

Thanks everyone for their comment and helping out a newbie in scala! :)

Comment: Can you give a hint about how one would do this using only `unfold`?

Comment: @ziggystar I'm not sure how to go about using `unfold`. I can see a solution based on indices, but it requires more tooling than just directly implementing `map`. Unless one uses mutable state on the function passed to `unfold`, which is downright ugly.

Comment: Thanks, I came to a similar conclusion. So we have to ask Andreas.

Comment: @ziggystar Is it Andreas who gave that homework? I'd certainly like to know if there's another way.

Comment: No, see first comment under OP.

Comment: @ziggystar, see my separate reply.

Answer (score 1):

[In reply to previous comments.]

I don't know which exact variant of unfold you are given. Assuming it's something like this (in Ocaml, sorry, don't have Scala installed right now):

```
(* unfold : ('a -> ('b * 'a) option) -> 'a -> 'b list *)

let rec unfold f x =
  match f x with
  | None -> []
  | Some (y, x') -> y :: unfold f x'
```

Then a solution for `map` is the following:

```
let map f = unfold (function [] -> None | x::xs -> Some (f x, xs))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. Took me some time to decipher the OCaml code. My problem was the definition of `def unfold(f: Int => Option(Int,Int), x: Int): List[Int]` in the OP (which is now removed) instead of `def unfold[A,B](f: A => Option(B,A), x: A): List[B]`, which makes much more sense.

Comment: Same for me. Something about the implementation of `unfold` was either wrong or confusing, though, reading it again, it seems to be correct. Weird.